# Cannot open database <database> requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user <user>

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

When I access the database with management studio, everything works, I access the tables... but when I run the Windows Service that is accessing the database with the same user, so, throws this error.

```
System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "sttcoletorsbvt" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'usr_stt_coletor'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_IServicoConfiguracaoColetor_3f81c81b8be24d3998bbc85dfa25d87f.SelecionarConfiguracao()
   at Infraero.TINE3.STTColetor.Negocio.Coletor.ColetarBilhetes(String arquivoParaProcessar)
   at Infraero.TINE3.STTColetor.WindowsService.ManipuladorBilhetes.RealizarProcedimentoColeta(String caminhoArquivo)
   at Infraero.TINE3.STTColetor.WindowsService.ServicoColetor.RealizarColeta()
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: did you check if you're passing the same exact password in your windows service that you are when you login to management studio?

Comment: Yes, I login with a copy/paste from app.config.

Comment: probably going to have to share your code you're using to connect.  also comment about if  this sql authentication or windows authentication? and is the database mentioned in the error the database you're trying to connect to.  also make sure you're even connecting to the right server, etc.

Comment: Is sql auth: the current config: `Data Source=s-vtgn02\prdsbvt04;Initial Catalog=sttcoletorsbvt;User ID=usr_stt_coletor;Password=<password>` the access of `usr_stt_coletor`: db_datareader and db_datawriter.

Comment: Do a SQL profiler capture and see what is really getting sent or happening

Answer (score 0):

Try ensuring that the user has access to the initial catalog in your connection string.  If your connection string doesn't have an initial catalog, add one that the user has access to.  This could explain why it works in one case and not the other.

Comment: the current config: `Data Source=s-vtgn02\prdsbvt04;Initial Catalog=sttcoletorsbvt;User ID=usr_stt_coletor;Password=<password>` the access of `usr_stt_coletor`: db_datareader and db_datawriter.